# My iteration doesn't work when it runs after the first time

Tags: python

When I enter the correct word, it prints out congratulations, but when I enter it for the second or third try, it doesn't work

```
 secret_word = "hello"
 tries = 1
 guess_word = input("Guess a word: ")
 while tries < 3:
        if  secret_word != guess_word:
            tries += 1 
            print("Sorry, word not found, you have", 4 - tries, "tries left")
            guess_word = input("Guess a word")
            if tries == 3:
                print("Sorry, you are out of tries, better luck next time !!!")
                break
        else:
                print("Congratulations! You've done it!")
                break
```

Comment: You'll never be able to get it on your last try because you will increment tries to 3, ask for an input, and immediately tell the user they are out of tries. This means you only get 2 attempts. It *is* possible to answer correctly on your second try.

Answer (score 2):

In this section of code:

```
            print("Sorry, word not found, you have", 4 - tries, "tries left")
            guess_word = input("Guess a word")
            if tries == 3:
                print("Sorry, you are out of tries, better luck next time !!!")
```

you don't check to see whether the guess was right before telling the user they've lost.  It might be easier if you base the loop on whether the guess was right, and use the `tries` counter to decide whether to break or continue:

```
secret_word = "hello"
tries = 0
while input("Guess a word: ") != secret_word:
    tries += 1
    if tries < 3:
        print(f"Sorry, word not found, you have {3 - tries} tries left")
    else:
        print("Sorry, you are out of tries, better luck next time !!!")
        break
else:
    print("Congratulations! You've done it!")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you could put this line,

> guess_word = input("Guess a word: ")

... in the while loop, so you wouldn't have 2 of the same lines.

You can also state the number of tries to 3 instead of 1. Set the number you want, and decrement downwards. To avoid code like, "4 - tries"

> print("Sorry, word not found, you have", **4 - tries**, "tries left")

```
secret_word = "hello"
tries = 3
while tries > 0:
    guess_word = input("Guess a word: ")
    if secret_word != guess_word:
        tries -= 1
        print("Sorry, word not found, you have", tries, "tries left")
        if tries == 0:
            print("Ran out of tries!")
            break
    else:
        print("Congratulations! You've done it!")
        break
```

Your current code only allows 2 tries to be made. The 3rd try even if you get it right, it will be thrown out. Let me know if there's anything wrong with my solution!

Answer (score -1):

When you say `while tries < 3` you only go up to `2` because thats the last whole number that's smaller than 3. If you want to include 3 you can change it to `while tries <= 3`

Answer (score -2):

tries can never reach `3` as you have put `while tries < 3`

change it to `tries<=3`